# Ad Sizes for iOS devices

Tags: ios, iphone, ads

I would like to add some custom ads at the bottom of an app that would rotate.  This would work on any device and only in portrait.  Is there a best practice with the image size?  Will one size work, or is there a way to pick a range depending on the device size?  The ad would be similar to what we see currently, just managed by my backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd probably want to keep it consistent with iAds.

> iAd supports different banner sizes for portrait and landscape apps.
>   The exact size of advertisements depends on the device the banner is
>   being shown on. On an iPhone, a portrait advertisement is 320 x 50
>   points and 480 x 32 points for a landscape advertisement. On an iPad,
>   a portrait advertisement is 768 x 66 points and 1024 x 66 points for a
>   landscape advertisement. In the future, additional sizes may be
>   exposed by iAd.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/BannerAdvertisements/BannerAdvertisements.html

If you are rolling your own you'd have to account for the device orientation i.e. AutoLayout / viewWillLayoutSubviews().

Comment: I saw that documentation.  I assume the Ad framework takes care of a lot of the plumbing on what size to show.  Is there anything third party out that handles that?